# phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, countable

I've uploaded the backup to a table, opening the table I see this:

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#601
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2038: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1984: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'alternativegirls',
string 'tgp_photo',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `tgp_photo`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#216: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'alternativegirls',
string 'tgp_photo',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `tgp_photo`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./index.php#53: include(./sql.php)
```

Inside phpMyAdmin...

PHP is 7.2, the server is Ubuntu 16.04, installed yesterday.

Looking for I saw that some have this error in their code, but I did not find anyone who received it in phpMyAdmin...

What should I do? Is that my error? A phpmyadmin error? wait update ? I go back to PHP 7.1?

Comment: Those who are facing problem as: `if ( count($articles)){..}` in **CodeIgniter**, they should use: `if ( count((array)$articles)){..}` as [here](https://github.com/processwire/processwire-issues/issues/408#issuecomment-337931543)

Comment: i had this issue on phpmyadmin v4.6 i updated to 4.8 it disappeared . , looks like it have something to do with mariadb 10.3  as i had not that issue on mariadb 10.1 with phpmyadmin 4.6

Comment: In my case the problem occured when I had installed php 7.3 while my phpMyAdmin was 4.7.1, I switched back to php 7.0 and it works fine or you shoud install version of phpMyAdmin compatible with php 7.3

Answer (score 1160):

Edit file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php` using this command:

```
sudo nano +613 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

On line **613** the count function always evaluates to true since there is no closing parenthesis after `$analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']`. Making the below replacements resolves this, then you will need to delete the last closing parenthesis on line **614**, as it's now an extra parenthesis.

Replace:

```
((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
    || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
        && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))
```

With:

```
((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
    || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
        && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
```

Restart the server apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Works on Ubuntu 18.04 with phpmyadmin installed using apt.

Comment: Worked in that I could select tables, but error returned when I tried to export Db

Comment: A bit more info on why this is working would be nice. Is it a bug? Looks like that to me...

Comment: I guess we all make mistakes. This cropped up for me after upgrading PHP from 7.0 -> 7.2, which corresponds to a change made to PHP's count() function: `count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.`

Comment: Bug has been reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1767361

Comment: This works for me, thanks!

If you get 500 error, check the parentheses before the "count":

 `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)`

Comment: If you face a similar problem in DB export you need to edit /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php, line 551 from  
_if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {  
to  
_if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {_  
Might be interesting for @alperian and others

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got `Error in processing request Error code: 500 Error text: Internal Server Error`. The solution of @Chandra Nakka fixed my problem.

Comment: Did not require restart, but never hurts.

Comment: Works! Did both edits (in the answer + @Bernd Schuhmacher), now no errors, export is fine. Ubuntu 18.04, php 7.2, MariaDB 10.1.34, phpmyadmin 4.6.6

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Got the same error as Jee. Chandra Nakka's methods fixed.

Comment: Not able to find Chandra Nakka's method, @AndréYuhai

Comment: @sawrubh because he changed his name I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536059/4796762

Comment: Thanks, 
Editing line: Line no 604 for method starting, The line number is 613 and 614 want change

Comment: If you are getting a 500 I also had to remove parenthesis after the line OP referenced. `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))`

Comment: Downvoted because, at today, may of 2019, it causes a server error

Comment: worked on ubntu 18.04 but why you restart the apache?

Comment: @BerndSchuhmacher this information was crucial to me. You should edit this answer to make this information more visible.
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: restart not needed

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.043 LTS with Package: phpmyadmin
Version: 4:4.6.6-5

Comment: If using MAMP on Windows you can find this file in "C:\MAMP\bin\phpMyAdmin\libraries" - restarted and it worked for me as well.

Comment: Works but keep in mind that the distro version of phpmyadmin for "18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)" version 4:4.6.6-5 still contains this error.

So remove the triple bracket and place it after the square on line 613

Comment: Works for me Feb 4, 2020

Comment: Had issues with importing database, but @BerndSchuhmacher's comment contained the fix.

Comment: Better Upgrade phpMyAdmin to a version, the bug is fixed! see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019751/1069083

Comment: I encountered the same error on my Raspberry Pi and this fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: I have faced the same problem at Debian Linux 10 and fixed it with the help of this. Thanks.

Comment: For me, this is worked: [Nye Liu](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890595#15)

Comment: Also read: https://devnote.in/count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object/

Comment: this answer works but you need to add another parenthesis before the count, here ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)

Answer (score 693):

## The Easiest Method:

Just run this below command line in terminal and come back to PhpMyAdmin.

```
sudo sed -i "s/|\s*\((count(\$analyzed_sql_results\['select_expr'\]\)/| (\1)/g" /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

---

## Manual Method:

Open **sql.lib.php** file

```
nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Find for `count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']` code on file. You can get this at line ~**613**. You can see this below wrong code

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

Just replace that wrong code with this below one

```
|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

Save the file and come to **PhpMyAdmin**.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04 at Aug 2018 :)

Comment: It looks like this is the same as Jacky Nguyen's answer and it has the same flaw as that answer (exports still have the bug)

Comment: It works in Ubuntu 18.04. I recomend to create a backup before ;)

Comment: Thanks!! This worked and also solved access denied errors for me Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 19.04. Thanks

Comment: worked on ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.2 on September  2019

Comment: If we carefully read the error message, which is "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable," it is clear this answer resolve the issue at hand.

Comment: A neat little trick to nano is, that you can type `nano +613 filename` in order to take you directly to the specific line.

Comment: Works un Ubuntu 16.04.6 with php 7.2.24, thanks so much!

Comment: working on ubuntu-16.04 [php 7.2] as of dated 2019-11-11 12:09:36

Comment: easiest method indeed. Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 running phpMyAdmin 4.6.6. Cheers mate!

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Comment: this is great, should I undo what I did from @Jacky 's answer?

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04!

Comment: I had to replace this in `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php` instead of the `/usr/share` location - Ubuntu server 18.04

Answer (score 113):

I found this [**PHP 7.2 count() - SYNTAX error in sql.lib.php**](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14973)

That perfectly works on my config:

```
Debian 9, 
PHP 7.2.3-1+0~20180306120016.19+stretch~1.gbp81bf3b (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 12:00:19) ( NTS )
```

**Open** `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`

**Change line**: Move parenthesis before **==**

> || **(**(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] **)** == 1)
>                   && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))

in

```
function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results){

return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
    && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
    && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
    && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
        || ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] ) == 1)
            && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))
    && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
 }
```

Comment: In the following line you will also have to remove one of the closing paranthesis at the end.

Comment: Thanks. How did such an error get released with an apt installable package? Just a bit ridiculous.

Comment: @floppes No, it is not correct. You SHOULD NOT remove that closing paranthesis. I have tested your way and it caused `server error`.
@loquace's answer should be the one to be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out for us and using bold font where it's needed. Neither the 1st nor the 2nd answers were clear enough for me because they didn't say what they were doing. Editing on nano isn't the same as gedit or whatever.

Answer (score 73):

tested on Debian, should works on Ubuntu:

1.) First download latest phpMyadmin file.

2.) Delete (make a backup) all previous version file located in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` directory.

3.) Uncompress to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` directory all files of latest phpmyadmin.

4.) Modify file `libraries/vendor_config.php` and change line:

```
define('CONFIG_DIR', '');
```

to

```
define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');
```

and

```
define('TEMP_DIR', './tmp/');
```

to

```
define('TEMP_DIR', '/tmp/');
```

5.) restart apache server and done.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, phpMyAdmin 4.8.0.1 - I needed to `mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp; chgrp www-data tmp; chmod g+w tmp;`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 just extracting it to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` worked. Did not need to follow the later steps.

Comment: @billynoah Same here with new install. I created the tmp directory, set it to 777,  restarted Apache, logged out of phpMyAdmin and the errors went away.

Comment: @JScarry- not sure it matters much but the directory only needs to be writeable by the webserver user (www-data) so changing group to www-data and setting permissions to 770 or 775 will work and keep things a bit tighter.

Comment: This Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 and thanks for the guide :)

Comment: Great solution! Works on 18.04

Comment: Can I update via terminal (Ubuntu 18.04) without having to download manually.

Answer (score 42):

**Edit file**: `'/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php'`

**Replace**: `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)`

**With**:  `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1`

this worked for me

Comment: Its worked for me based on condition u have fix internal 500 error was solved, but old error issue "phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable" is not solved.

Comment: this seems to work for me but does any one know why this has happened? My phpmyadmin was working just fine and then all the sudden I logged in today and it appeared to have this issue? 

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Works  on UBuntu 18.04 , wing Nginx , php 7.2

Answer (score 37):

If someone have similar error in DB export page (I had this issue in Ubuntu 18.04), then replace line 551 in file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php` with code

```
if ($options != null && (is_array($options) || $options instanceof Countable) && count($options) > 0) {
```

Comment: This helped me as well, but I had to do both the answer and this. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This worked to get rid of the error messages, but I think it then avoids the if statement all together and I don't get anything in my database export (with a bunch of errors showing at the bottom after refreshing the page upon completing a database export with a tiny file footprint)

Comment: On Debian 9 
replace the line 551: ``if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {``
with : ``if ($options != null) {``
then you can export

Comment: This is the fix for the error ending 551 - as error is at line 551. The other fix is good too but is a fix for another problem. This should be the accepted answer for this problem.

Answer (score 34):

```
Works on UBUNTU 18.04 


Edit file: '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php'
Replace: (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
With:  ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)

Restart the server
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This worked for me on 18.04, thanks! No need even to restart the server - PHP is interpreted 'live'.

Comment: @JelleVeraa , You are the special case  hehehe ;)

Answer (score 29):

phpmyadmin 4.7.4 is supposed to have "Fixed several compatibility issues with PHP 7.2"

Chances are you have an older version of phpmyadmin.

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news/2017/8/24/phpmyadmin-474-released/

Answer (score 25):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

These are the steps which worked for me. Many, many thanks to William Desportes for providing the automatic updates on their Ubuntu PPA.

**Step 1** ([from William Desportes post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59694448/2581236))
$ `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa`

**Step 2** 
$ `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade`

**Step 3**
$ `sudo service mysql restart`

If you have issues restarting mysql, you can also restart with the following sequence
$ `sudo service mysql stop;`
$ `sudo service mysql start;`

Comment: Solves the issue on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24):

Proceed following steps at ubuntu-18.04:

**Step 1)** locate `sql.lib.php`

It will show something like:

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

**Step 2)** Open terminal (Alt t) and write:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/pma-configure
```

**Step 3)**`sudo gedit /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`
and search below function:

```
 

    function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results)
     {
        return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
            && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
                || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
                || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
                || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
            && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
            && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
                || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
                    && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))
            && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
     }
```

**Step 4)** Replace above function with:

```
     function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results)
     {
        return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
            && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
                || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
                || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
                || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
            && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
            && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
                || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
                    && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
            && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
     }
```

**Step 4)** Save & close file and below command on terminal

```
sudo /usr/sbin/pma-secure
```

**Step 5)** `sudo service mysql reload`

**Step 6)** `sudo service apache2 reload`

It works for me.. 
Goodluck

Comment: The MySQL and apache reload are not necessary.

Comment: I got this message after file modifications : "— root@Lalla:~# /usr/sbin/pma-secure —
Securing phpMyAdmin installation... —
***Setup script won't be able to write configuration.*** —
root@Lalla:~# "

Answer (score 24):

> open this file: '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php'

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

> press ctrl+w to search (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] ==
>   1)

```
Find: count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)

Replace With:  (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

> Restart the server

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

moreover, If you still facing same issue then do following.

> open this file /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php
```

> Find :  if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {

```
Ctrl+w : if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {
```

replace with following code

```
if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {
```

now save and restart the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: You simply added a brace. But thanks.
I removed the extra brace at the end of the line

Comment: I have xampp installed on my mac, I couldnt find /usr/share/phpmyadmin folder and hence '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php' this dosent exist for me, can you help in that ?

Answer (score 22):

I think the best option is to update Phpmyadmin to a version which has this already fixed.

Until it is published as a deb, you could do it like in [@crimson-501 answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1057085/25896) which I will copy below:

- Your first step is to install PMA (phpMyAdmin) from the official Ubuntu repo: `apt-get install phpmyadmin`.
- Next, cd into usr/share directory: `cd /usr/share`.
- Third, remove the phpmyadmin directory: `rm -rf phpmyadmin`.
- Now we need to download the latest PMA version onto our system (Note that you need wget: `apt-get install wget`): `wget -P /usr/share/ "https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.9.4/phpMyAdmin-4.9.4-english.zip"`
  Let me explain the arguments of this command, -P defines the path and "the link.zip" is currently (7/17/18) the latest version of PMA. You can find those links [HERE](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/).
- For this next step you need unzip (`apt-get install unzip`): `unzip phpMyAdmin-4.9.4-english.zip`. We just unzipped PMA, now we will move it to it's final home.
- Lets use the `cp` (copy) command to move our files! Note that we have to add the `-r` argument since this is a folder. `cp -r phpMyAdmin-4.9.4-english phpmyadmin`.
- Now it's time to clean up: `rm -rf phpMyAdmin-4.9.4-english`.

### Keep Reading!

You might now notice two errors after you log into PMA.

```
the configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret). phpmyadmin
The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this.
```

However, these issues are relatively easy to fix. For the first issue all you have to do is grab your editor of choice and edit `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` but there's a problem, we removed it! That's ok, all you have to do is: `cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin` & `cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php`.

- We will now add our Blowfish Secret! `nano config.inc.php` and copy the dynamically generated secret from near the bottom of this page: https://www.question-defense.com/tools/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator.

Example phpMyAdmin Blowfish Secret Variable Entry:

```
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '{^QP+-(3mlHy+Gd~FE3mN{gIATs^1lX+T=KVYv{ubK*U0V'; 
/* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

Now save and close the file.

- Now we will create a tmp directory for PMA: `mkdir tmp` & `chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp`. The last command allows the Apache web server to own the tmp directory and edit it's contents.

Comment: This answer has been incredibly useful! Solved the problem for me! Thanks!

PS: You can find blowfish generators online.

Comment: And the solution at this link: https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/  follows a similar plan, except replaces the blowfish steps with easier ones..

Comment: This is a much better solution compared to editing older versions' config files.

Comment: This is the best solution. Following this link: https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/ I was able to remove the count-parameter error and the Server error 500 error (which is not removed by the accepted answer). Definitely the real problem was the by default installed phpmyadmin version. Thanks a lot. +1.

Answer (score 21):

Try replace this function in file:
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php

```
function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results)
{
    return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
        && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
        && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
        && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
            || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
                && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
        && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this line is where i was mistaken at the end where i had 3 closing bracket insted i needed 2 closing brackets only && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')). Worked on phpmyadmin 4.6, php 7.2.10 , ubuntu 18.4.1

Comment: This worked.  There are two changes, on line 613 add missing closing parenthesis for `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)` should be `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)` and remove extra parenthesis on line 614 `&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))` should be `&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))`.

Answer (score 15):

Ubuntu 18.10 (December, 2018)

Line 613, 614, 615, replace with:

```
        || count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1
            && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
    && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
```

Comment: It's worked for me.. No need to upgrade mysql or anything... Thanks @ole

Answer (score 15):

Work for me.. Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Find for `count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']` code on file. You can get this at line ~613.

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

Just replace with code :

```
|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

Save the file and reload PhpMyAdmin.

**Done!!!**

Comment: In line 613, change to `|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1`

Answer (score 12):

For my version of phpmyadmin (4.6.6deb5), I found line 613, and realized the count() parentheses were not closed properly. To fix this temporarily until the next release, just change:

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

to:

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1
```

Comment: There were a missing parenthesis to close the function call || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1 is the correct statement

Comment: file path is  "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php" for those who don't know where to find it.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me;

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Line No : 614

Replace two codes :

Replace:

```
(count($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’] == 1)
```

With:

```
(count($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’]) == 1)
```

AND

Replace:

```
($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’][0] == ‘*’)))
```

With:

```
($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’][0] == ‘*’))
```

save, exit and run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: worked for me Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Answer (score 8):

Works on UBUNTU 16.04.3
Just open

usr/share/libraries/sql.lib.php

modify

`|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)`

To

`|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)`

Answer (score 8):

This is fixed in later versions of PHPMyAdmin. The Ubuntu Software Repositories for Ubuntu 18.04.2 holds version 4.6.6.5, while they're currently at 4.9.0.1. Updating your PHPMyAdmin installation will fix this problem, but might prove to be riskier than just editing that one line of code. Here's how I did it on my Ubuntu Server. Steps are essentially the same (with a different path) for all operating systems.

1. Download [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

```sh
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.9.0.1/phpMyAdmin-4.9.0.1-all-languages.zip
unzip phpMyAdmin-4.9.0.1-all-languages.zip
```

2. Backup your old PHPMyAdmin installation.

```sh
cp -r /usr/share/phpmyadmin ~/phpmyadmin-backup
```

3. Drop your new PHPMyAdmin on your old PHPMyAdmin

```sh
cd phpMyAdmin-4.9.0.1-all-languages
rm -r /usr/share/phpmyadmin/doc/html
cp -R * /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

**Verify that it works.** If it doesn't, welll... You have a backup, so restore it and manually edit the faulty line. In my own personal experience, I discovered after doing this that version 4.6.6.5 was not only riddled with bugs, but also incredibly slow compared to the new 4.9.0.1. The speed increase was pure magic for something I though was of "WordPress" quality.

Comment: I would switch the order of 1 and 2, and before wget I would **cd /tmp** but aside from that, excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This worked well for me on **Ubuntu 18.04**.

Open **sql.lib.php** file

```
nano +613 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Replace this wrong code:

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

With this one:

```
|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

Save the file.

Restart your server with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And refresh **PhpMyAdmin**

Comment: A server restart is not needed for this.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade to phpMyAdmin 4.8.3. this solves the PHP 7.2 compatibility issues

Answer (score 5):

Edit file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php' Replace: 
(make backup)

```
"|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1) 
&&($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))) 
&& count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;"
```

With:

```
"|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1) 
&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*') 
&& (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1));"
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi the following solve my same problem absolutely (import/export and so on):

[Fix Bug Phpmyadmin [plugin_interface.lib.php] + Php7.2 + Ubuntu 16.04](https://medium.com/@chaloemphonthipkasorn/%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89-bug-phpmyadmin-php7-2-ubuntu-16-04-92b287090b01)

so... under ubuntu 18.04, mysql, php7.2:
Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php
```

**Find the following line(ctrl+f):**

```
if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {
```

it was on line #551 for me

and **change for following:**

```
if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {
```

**ctrl+s for save the changes**

and in terminal: ctrl+c for get back promt...

**and:** `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

"I think in new php version.It can’t use count() or sizeof() with un array type. Force parameter to array is easy way to solve this bug,..."

Thanks for the original author for the problem solving! I try to share it!

Answer (score 5):

`|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1`

This is what I changed in line 614 and phpmyadmin works without any error.
Need one `(` before count, and one `)` before `==` . That's it.

Answer (score 5):

Just correct the `count()` function and closing parentheses
from line 604 till 615 in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php` file:

```php
function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results)
{
    return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
        && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
        && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
        && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
            || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
                && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
        && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Much clearer and simpler than the other answers! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of above solution but didn't work for me.

Try this:-

Install required version of PHP(in my case 7.0) and then in terminal, type

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Output will be like this :-

[image]

Then you can switch to any version of PHP by simply entering the selection number(in my case 1).

Hope this may help other -:)

Answer (score 3):

Open the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/sql.lib.php` file with elevated privileges, and edit the following in the function `PMA_isRememberSortingOrder()`:

1. ~ line 613 to fix the initial error:

   - Replace `|| count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)`
   - With `|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)`
2. ~ line 614 to fix the 500 error that will probably follow:

   - Replace `&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))`
   - With `&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))`

Restart your Apache server: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Tested on Linux Mint 19.1 based on Ubuntu 18.04, with PhpMyAdmin 4.6.6 and PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 3):

Replace Function:

```
function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results) {
return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
    &&!(
        $analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse']
    )&&
    $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']&&
    (
        empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'])||
        count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'])==1&&
        $analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'
    )
    && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the phpmyadmin ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Actually a really useful answer besides other ones fixing the source's bug

Comment: That's right, I forgot to mention it but I did an upgrade in my case. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get purge phpmyadmin
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Fixed it for me, on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Edit file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`

See an error on your error

```
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2038: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1984: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
```

go to this line and remove the function call.

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when using windows and the responses above solved it for me, however when i switched to linux (ubuntu 18.04 LTS) I had the same issue and couldn't figure out how to solve it because I didn't see the file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php'.

This sql.lib.php file wasn't in the share folder or the phpmyadmin/libraries folder of my /opt/lampp directory - since I was using xampp on my ubuntu.
Based on the update made to the xampp (because I used the latest installation as of now) setup.

The answer is still to replace: `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)`

With: `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1`

However the file to look for is `Sql.php` found in `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Sql.php`

Future updates or if you still don't find it: use `grep -r 'count($analyzed_sql_results' /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin` to search for matching documents in your directory and edit accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are all editing or updating from our files

For those who want automatic updates you can use our Ubuntu PPA

[sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515#issuecomment-548521407)

And for Debian users you will need to wait for next version of Debian or use PPA

Ubuntu 20 has phpMyAdmin 4.9 or a later version

[Debian issue on our tracker](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15236#issuecomment-569642409)

[Countable issues on our tracker](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20label%3Abug%20countable%20is%3Aclosed)

TLDR
Update to latest 4.9 or 5.0 version to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 with MariaDb and Nginx,  I solved it with updating file /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php as follows:

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1
```

The answer mentioned by @Nguyen throws a 500 error saying:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php on line 614"
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error in code in conf file may vary (@Jacky Nguyen vs @ĦΔŇĐŘΔ ŇΔҜҜΔ answers),
the **general solution**  answer would be to

a) correct the condition logic in conf file to make sense

(x)or b) install corrected/current phpmyadmin

As for a)

1. open the file with error code
   For the terminal people: `sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`

   For the regular folks: `sudo gedit /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`
2. find the condition - basically search for `$analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']`
3. now the logic  should be to check whether this sub array is empty, or, whether it has just 1 element with a value "`*`
4. so basically the block 
   between `&& $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']`
   and `&& count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1`

   should look something like this

> ```
> && (
>     empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) //the sub array is empty,
>     || //or,
>     (
>         (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1) //it has just 1 element
>         && //and at the same time
>         ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*') //the 1 element value is "*"
>     )
> )
> ```

## This is a good example of why to indent and beautify your code, if it would be indeted correctly, I believe this would never happen, or at least, would be more easily found.

Comment: I have xampp installed on my mac, I couldnt find /usr/share/phpmyadmin folder and hence '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php' this dosent exist for me, can you help in that ?

Comment: @SaurabhVerma perform a file search for sql.lib.php or for the phpmyadmin folder - if you have phpmyadmin, it must be installed somewhere

Answer (score 1):

**is_countable** function introduced in (PHP 7 >= 7.3.0)

is_countable — Verify that the contents of a variable is a countable value.

use this function following way ::

`is_countable ( $var )`

It will return boolean value. For more detail please visit on http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-countable.php

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@jbator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51080157/1440242), you can edit `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php` and replace this line:

```
if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {
```

with these lines:

```
if ($options != null &&
   ((is_array($options) || $options instanceof Countable) && count($options) > 0) ||
   (method_exists($options, 'getProperties') && $options->getProperties() != null && (is_array($options->getProperties()) || $options->getProperties() instanceof Countable) && count($options->getProperties()) > 0)) {
```

In this way, we won't have empty exported file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: https://devanswers.co/problem-php-7-2-phpmyadmin-warning-in-librariessql-count/

Firstly, backup sql.lib.php before editing.
Edit sql.lib.php in nano.

$ sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php

Press CTRL + W and search for (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)

Replace it with ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)

Save file and exit. (Press CTRL + X, press Y and then press ENTER)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an automated patching script I threw together utilizing `Chandra Nakka`'s answer.

```sh
FILE="/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php"
PATTERN="(count(\$analyzed_sql_results\['select_expr'\] == 1)"

echo "Verifying broken code in $FILE"

if grep -q "$PATTERN" "$FILE"; then
  LINE_NUMBER=$(grep -n "$PATTERN" "$FILE" | cut -d : -f 1)
  echo "Broken code found on line: $LINE_NUMBER"
  BEFORE_CODE=$(sed -n "$LINE_NUMBER"p "$FILE")

  echo -e "\nCreating backup of $FILE"
  sudo cp "$FILE" "$FILE-backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S")"
  echo "Backup created at: $FILE-backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S")"

  echo -e "\nApplying fix"
  sudo sed -i "s/|\s*\((count(\$analyzed_sql_results\['select_expr'\]\)/| (\1)/g" $FILE
  AFTER_CODE=$(sed -n "$LINE_NUMBER"p "$FILE")

  # Trim before and after code with xargs
  echo "BEFORE: $(echo $BEFORE_CODE | xargs)"
  echo " AFTER: $(echo $AFTER_CODE | xargs)"
else
  echo "Broken code not found. Maybe it's already been patched "
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

none of these solutions worked for me
you need to update phpmyadmin to the latest, follow instructions here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/947805/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-revisited