# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that im plements Countable error based on the array size

Tags: php, arrays, json, count

This error is generated in the code below only when the returned array is too long. With short arrays (I do not know exactly how much) does not occur.

```
$phone_numbers = array();
if(!empty($_POST['phone_numbers']))
    $phone_numbers = json_decode($_POST['phone_numbers']);
    $phone_numbers_var = str_repeat('?,', count(json_decode($_POST['phone_numbers'])) - 1) . '?'; // <-- error line
```

Is there a limit to the count () parameter?

Comment: Is this a PHP question?

Comment: Why don't you use `count` on the `$phone_numbers` instead of `json_decode` twice? And no, there is no limit on `count`

Comment: @dWinder I've tried both ways and the error persists

Comment: Unless it was double encoded, the second decode will return null regardless of the array size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343557/count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-countable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check you $_POST['phone_numbers'] what is getting

remember that :

`var_dump(count(null))`;`var_dump(count(false))`;

will output :

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
```

I think is the PHP version 7.2's count is a little weird... but you can try something like this :

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables

**EDIT :**

For just comment :

```
$POST['phone_numbers'] = [165567, 545675, 655666];
```

if you try to do this:

```
json_decode($POST['phone_numbers']);
```

will return this :

```
WARNING json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line number 4
```

and count of that... you know .. just do:

```
count($POST['phone_numbers']);
```

Comment: $phone_numbers returns [165567, 545675, 655666, ..., n]

Comment: @afazolo so do the `count` on him and not on the decode of the `POST`

Comment: The problem appears to occur due to the integrity of the returned data. Thaks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is funny but it seems that if in the array there is some digit starting with 0 the error occurs. When I remove the initial 0 is ok.

```
 $phone_numbers = [011364346387, 33334444, ..., n] //error
 $phone_numbers = [11364346387, 33334444, ..., n] //is ok!
```