# why im getting error count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in laravel?

Tags: laravel, scope

I tried to define a local scope in my project to show popular(most downloaded)in my Home Page...so this is my File Model codes:

```
        public function scopePopular($query)
        {
        return $query->orderBy('file_download_num');
        }
```

As you know "file_download_num" is the field in database im trying to get data from...
so this is how I used this scope in my HomeController:

```
        $popularFiles = File::Popular()->get();
```

I didn't use `count()` method in my Controller or Model!But still getting Error!so any suggestion?
notice:php version is 7.3

Comment: provide the stack trace

Comment: @lagbox how should I do?

Comment: @navid hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53425861/6850994

Comment: @Poldo Unfortunately didnt work...

Comment: It should be `File::popular()->get()`.

Answer (score -1):

I found that adding a `toArray()` method in controller can help `count()` method work correctly...it worker for me...so controller should be like this:

```
$popularFiles = File::Popular()->get()->toArray();
```