# Getting error on php artisan scout:import

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

I wanted to run

```
php artisan scout:import App\\Product
```

but composer showing

```
  [ErrorException]
  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

In my composer.json I have this

```
  "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "laravelcollective/html":"5.3.*",
        "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/scout": "1.0",
        "teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver": "1.*"
    },
```

I can't fighure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented change in PHP 7.2. You need to either update Laravel to 5.6 or downgrade PHP to version 7.1.

> https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables
>
> [count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343557/count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-countable)

Comment: where should I downgrade php?  In my project or xampp older version?

Comment: @Md.ShamvilHossain it'd be a good idea to update laravel, as php 7.1 is at EOL