# How to install phpMyAdmin 4.7.7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I need the latest version, not the 4.6.6 that is available at [here](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin/+packages). I read the [manual](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#ubuntu) and other threads, but everything keeps pointing back to this older version. The reason I need the latest is that the old version doesn't work well on PHP 7.2, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co).

Isn't it possible to "manually" do an install/upgrade just by downloading the latest version from [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/)? The contents of the archive look similar to what I get from the "phpMyAdmin PPA". Can't I just overwrite some files manually in the file system to upgrade my version to the latest? Is there a command that starts the installation, if I have the archive unpacked under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Identify Apache’s DocumentRoot

```
 $ grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Download Latest Version of phpMyAdmin

```
 $ cd /var/www/html
 $ sudo wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.7/phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-english.tar.gz
 $ ls
 index.html phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-english.tar.gz
```

Extract the files

```
 sudo tar xvzf phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-english.tar.gz
```

Rename the folder

```
 sudo mv phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-english phpmyadmin
```

Remove the files

```
 sudo rm phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-english.tar.gz
```

Secure /phpmyadmin Directory

```
 $ sudo adduser phpmyadmin
 Adding user `phpmyadmin' ...
 Adding new group `phpmyadmin' (1001) ...
 Adding new user `phpmyadmin' (1001) with group `phpmyadmin' ...
 Creating home directory `/home/phpmyadmin' ...
 Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
 Enter new UNIX password:
 Retype new UNIX password:
 passwd: password updated successfully


 sudo chown -R phpmyadmin.phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

Update phpMyAdmin config.inc With Install Wizard

```
 $ cd /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
 sudo mkdir config
 sudo chmod o+rw config
 sudo cp config.sample.inc.php config/config.inc.php
 sudo chmod o+w config/config.inc.php
```

On AWS Cloud9:

```
 cd -
 sudo mv phpmyadmin ~/workspace/phpmyadmin
```

Run phpMyAdmin Install Wizard

```
 http://example.com/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php
```

if you work in the localhost

```
 http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php
```

Under the “Servers” section, click on “New Server.”

Under the “Authentication” tab, type in your MySQL root password in the “Password for Config Auth” box and then click “Apply.”

Remove the phpMyAdmin /config directory for security.

```
 sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/config
```

> source: http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu/

Comment: It worked, very cool! Look, I have everything on the latest version now :) https://i.snag.gy/aRm53n.jpg

Comment: From the comment of @alebal below: 
`In my documentroot there is no phpMyAdmin folder (I think it is /usr/share/phpmyadmin), I have to create it? Should I find the existing one? Should I delete it?`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the updated version in ubuntu you have to disable the current phpmyadmin from apache.

You can do this by typing "rm /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf". This is symlinked to /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf which then again this file is also symlinked to /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Alternatively you can use the "a2disconf phpmyadmin".