# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, wordpress

When I try and view the wp_posts table in phpmyadmin, I see this error message, but have no idea what it means and have never seen it before.

Can someone help me try and get rid of this somehow?

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'afterhours',
string 'wp_posts',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/original/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_posts`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'afterhours',
string 'wp_posts',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/original/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_posts`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co)

Answer (score 32):

This appears to be a duplicate of [phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co/50536059)

According to the top answer on the linked post, it looks like there may be an error in the ./libraries/sql.lib.php that is causing the code to attempt a count() function on something other than an array (or an object that implements "Countable"). To fix it (according to the linked response):

Edit file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php' and replace

```
(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

With:

```
(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1
```

This works because:

- count cannot be performed on a non-array (hence your error, "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable")
- "== 1" in count() is an equivalency test, not an array
- removing "== 1" from count() leaves a count(*array*) function, which works.

Comment: I don't have this line. There are no results even for `] == 1`.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but it does not work for me.

Comment: FYI I dug into the github history and found that line in an old version https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blame/5a0836262bae583a5ac62c6ec04524e7c8052005/libraries/Sql.php .. if it's not in your version, yours is probably fixed. Frustrating that in this, and a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co/50536059, people don't report their version of phpMyAdmin.  Knowing your Ubuntu or PHP version does not help much :)

Comment: works a treat :-) thank you

Answer (score 15):

I solved the problem by validating if it really is an array using the is_array() function like this:

```
if (is_array($yourArray)) {
    //Your count()
}
```