# What might be wrong when i want to run php artisan serve

Tags: laravel

I came across this error when I tried to run php artisan serve. I downloaded this project and tried to run it encountered this error instead.

Is there any solution that you guys can help me. Thanks in advance. I am using xampp as a host server for my project.

```
ErrorException in Builder.php line 1185: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
    in Builder.php line 1185
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\bootup-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php', '1185', array('scope' => object(Closure), 'parameters' => array(object(Builder)), 'query' => object(Builder)))
    at count(null) in Builder.php line 1185
    at Builder->callScope(object(Closure)) in Builder.php line 1216
    at Builder->applyScopes() in Builder.php line 314
    at Builder->get() in HomeController.php line 30
    at HomeController->index()
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(HomeController), 'index'), array()) in Controller.php line 80
    at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(HomeController), object(Route), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
    at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
    at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(HomeController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', 'index') in Route.php line 174
    at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TagstripMiddleware.php line 19
    at TagstripMiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(TagstripMiddleware), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
    at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\bootup-master\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: which laravel version you are currently using?

Comment: and which version of PHP you're using?

Comment: This error is due to PHP version. Which version are you using?

Comment: the php version is 7.3.11

Comment: and your laravel version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110044/10697521

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the `PHP` version. Most probably `PHP 7.2` version. See below:

[Document changes of PHP 7.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables)

To solve this issue:

> Donwgrade your `PHP` version

**OR**

Modify line `1185` of the 
`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php` file

```
$originalWhereCount = count ($ query-> wheres);
```

**to**

```
$originalWhereCount = 0;
if (is_array ($ query-> wheres) || is_object ($ query-> wheres)) {
    $originalWhereCount = count ($ query-> wheres);
}
```