# PhpMyAdmin Error - Export/Import

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I can log into the server no problem. However, when I click on any database and select export/import I get:

```
    Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#532
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/display_export.lib.php#380: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Export',
array,
```

Ubuntu 16.04

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.33-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

PHP 7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2018 08:44:50) ( NTS )

Comment: Check the below link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co/50536059

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed by just upgrading phpmyadmin to the latest version (4.9.1 at the time of this post). It solved the problem, after I tried other solutions such as updating the sql.lib.php file as seen in this  post [phpmyadmin import-export error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co)