# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently getting this Error:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\theme.php on line 629

and I don't have an Idea how to fix it.

Comment: Turn off your WP_DEBUG to false

Comment: @SudharshanNair thanks but the WP_DEBUG on the wp-config file is set to false but still I'm getting the error

Comment: add these lines `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors',0)`

Comment: @HarrisNgwenya try uninstalling jetpack plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co)

Comment: @SudharshanNair please update your answer and add a `;` on the last line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co)

Accepted answer from that page is given below.

Edit file /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Replace: `count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)`

With:  `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)`

Restart the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using WordPress make sure the_content is inside the loop. That was my issues.

```
<?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result->num_rows){
        $row = $result->fetch_array();

//use this instead of count()
```