# PHP 7.2 - Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, session, post, count, php-7.2

I just upgraded my PHP installation from version **5.6** to **7.2**. I used the `count()` function on my login page like so:

```php
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username');
    $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '';
    
    if (count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
        header("Location: /");
    } else {
        $message = 'Sorry, those credentials do not match';
    }
endif;
```

After searching, I found questions and answers similar to this one, but they all were related to WordPress, and I couldn’t find a solution for **Pure PHP**.

Comment: I guess $results is not an array? Try checking it with bool is_array ( mixed $var ) before checking other stuff.

Comment: Dump `$results`.

Comment: "**Pure PHP**" [count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-changelog)

Comment: I think the problem with "$results". can you update your question like, how you get data into $results variable?

Comment: Alright, I updated the question and added the full code.

Comment: Dump `$results`: `var_dump($results)`. It will probably be returning a bool (false) as the query might have failed.

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806221/3016038 for php is_countable function

Comment: here is quick fix https://sdtuts.com/warning-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-fixed/ even parameter not `array`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PDO `fetch` returns false on failure. So you need to check this case too:

```
if ($results && count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
    header("Location: /");
} else {
    $message = 'Sorry, those credentials do not match';
}
```

Comment: Not *'may return false on failure'*, it *will* return false on failure: '*The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.*'

Comment: @Script47Thanks, updated accordingly.

Comment: you can use !is_null() to solve this issue.

Comment: `count($results) > 0` is a needless/redundant check after `$results`, right?

Comment: you can also use >>  error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_WARNING );
to mak the warning silance