# PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\\htdocs\my.php

Tags: php, joomla3.0, countable

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\htdocs..\components\com_jcomments\tpl\joomspirit_theme\tpl_form.php

```
$customBBCodes = $this->getVar('comments-form-custombbcodes');
if (count($customBBCodes)) {
    foreach($customBBCodes as $code) {
        if ($code->button_enabled) {
            $k = 'custombbcode' . $code->id;
            $title = trim(JCommentsText::jsEscape($code->button_title));
            $text = empty($code->button_prompt) ? JText::_('BBCODE_HINT_ENTER_TEXT') : JText::_($code->button_prompt);
            $open_tag = $code->button_open_tag;
            $close_tag = $code->button_close_tag;
            $icon = $code->button_image;
            $css = $code->button_css;
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this script in my Joomla 3.0 application with PHP7.3 on Apache.

Comment: `var_dump($customBBCodes)`

Comment: So `$customBBCodes` is not as you expect an array or object. Check what `$this->getVar('comments-form-custombbcodes');` is returning

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `if (count($customBBCodes)) {`? This seems totally unnecessary here.

Comment: Since we don't know `$customBBCodes`'s data type or value, this question needs better diagnostic detail to be appropriately/accurately answered.  Offering `is_array()` without knowing what the actual and expected range of data types are -- is premature.

Comment: I expect a similar fate as this page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51594817/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must add
       `if(is_array($customBBCodes)){`

all change to

```
   `$customBBCodes = $this->getVar('comments-form-custombbcodes');
    if(is_array($customBBCodes)){
        if (count($customBBCodes)) {
            foreach($customBBCodes as $code) {
                if ($code->button_enabled) {
                    $k = 'custombbcode' . $code->id;
                    $title = trim(JCommentsText::jsEscape($code->button_title));
                    $text = empty($code->button_prompt) ? JText::_('BBCODE_HINT_ENTER_TEXT') : JText::_($code->button_prompt);
                    $open_tag = $code->button_open_tag;
                    $close_tag = $code->button_close_tag;
                    $icon = $code->button_image;
                    $css = $code->button_css;`
```