# count() parameter must be an array or an object that implements countable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is code here:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $admin=admin::where('email',$request->email)->first();
    if(count($admin))
    {
       if($admin->status==0){
           return ['email'=>'inactive','password'=>'You are not an active person, Please contact to admin'];
           }
           else{
               return ['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'status'=>1];
           }
       }
       return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }
```

When i run the code this error become:

> "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Comment: You are fetching first record which match the email it will never return any error.

Comment: You can try the is_countable function of php. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806221/3016038

Comment: here is quick fix https://sdtuts.com/warning-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-fixed/ even parameter is not an `array`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You may cast a variable to array. But be careful: using `array($variable)`  will give you **incorrect** result, returning an array with a single value of $variable in it, always returning 1 as a count.

`(array)` type casting operator must be used instead:

```
count((array)$variable));
```

Comment: Be careful.. If $variable is already an array it will be [[$variable]] and count will be 1

Comment: This is wrong, count will always be 1. You're counting an array with a single value of $variable in it, doesn't matter what $variable contains.

Comment: If answer is wrong, it must be fixed, not yelled at

Answer (score 45):

First of all you must understand that every error message PHP generates is meant to help you, and to make your code cleaner and less error-ridden.

When your code contains a bug, your best bet is to *fix* it, not to *brush it off*. Most answers here helps you with the latter. But you should really consider doing the former.

Every error message helps you to find a bug in the code. It means that errors shouldn't be intentional or "habitual". This way you won't have to silence them, and every error will mean that your code indeed encountered a bug.

Like in your case. You are using `count()` not on purpose. Not to actually count any values but only to tell whether returned value is empty or not. For this, you can use the variable itself:

```
if ($admin)
```

which is perfectly valid in PHP. Or, if you want to be more Catholic than the Pope, you can make it more strict but still on purpose

```
if ((bool)$admin === true)
```

So you should do every time when a function may return either `false` or `array`. This way, when accessing the returned value inside `if`, you will never get an error related to improper use of arrays. Unless the returned value will be non-empty and not an array - a situation for which this error message was invented exactly for!

So just make sure that every function that should return an array, returns an array, or any variable that should contain an array, contains an array. And you won't see this error again. Unless, due to some error, your code will return a non-array value unexpectedly. And this error message will *help* you to pinpoint this problem.

When things are not under your control, like, you need to get an array from an outside variable, do a *validation* first. For example, in case you are expecting an array from a form, that is obligatory, validate it and return an error, like

```
if (!$isset($_POST['options']) || !is_array($_POST['options'])) {
   // inform the user ad stop execution
} else {
    $options = $_POST['options'];
}
// now you can safely use count() on $options
```

In case the array is optional, you may initialize it as empty array:

```
if (!$isset($_POST['options'])) {
    $options = [];
} elseif (!is_array($_POST['options'])
   // inform the user ad stop execution
} else {
    $options = $_POST['options'];
}
// now you can safely use count() on $options
```

And only as a last resort you may silence this error, using a condition like this

```
count((is_countable($admin) ? $admin :[]))
```

or casting offered below

Comment: FWIW: is_countable() is introduced in PHP7.3.

Comment: While this will remove the error, it is still not returning the actual count of $admins.

Answer (score 10):

Note that here, When you use the `count()` method, there should be countable element, like an array or object that implement `ArrayAccess`.

```
Admin::where('email',$request->email)->first();
```

But the `first()` method give you single element, not a collection or array. The `get()` method returns you countable a collection with found elements

Instead of using count you can directly check variable itself is it defined or null

```
if($admin){
  // do something here
}
```

or you can use `is_null()` method

```
if(!is_null($admin)){
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: i try first method and use if($admin) but error comes it go on next and show blank page not showing if block message statment

Comment: and if i use get() method and if($admin) then this error comes "Property [status] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: @faraz error totally make sense because get method gives you a collection. And before the getting status, you need to select item first. like `$admin->{0}->status`, And I don't know what are you doing with credentials information so I can't know that why you're getting blank page. You can anytime check your code using dd method. For example put a dd method inside of if statment and check is if statement works well ? Or share with us more of your code to help you

Answer (score 5):

You can cast the variable to an array:

```
count((array)$variable);
```

If it's null then it will become an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

You should check if it is null instead of count, because you ask for one result with `first()`
just this

```
if($admin)
```

will do it.

if you use return a collection using `->get()` then you can check `$admin->count()`.

Answer (score 2):

`$admin` variable is neither array nor object that implements countable. When you use `first()` the result will be a model object if record is found else it will be null. For this condition you can use:

```
if (!empty($admin)) {
    //
}
```

Just replace `if (count($admin))` with `if (!empty($admin))`.

And when you use `get()` method to get multiple records you can check by:

```
if ($admins->count() > 0) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Well,
$admin=Admin::where('email',$request->email)->first();
//It will always return an **object**.
And make sure you included Admin model in your controller like as.
Use App\Admin;
at the same time check that you will have to mention which field of table needs to be fillable like in your model such as 
protected $fillable = [
'first_name',
'last_name'
];

whatever data you will going to save in your database.
and then check object is null or not
I mean is.

if($admin && $admin!==null){
  //do whatver you want to do.
}
```

Comment: Have you mention Admin model in controller.
and one more thing you need to do is.
$request->input('email');
first make this change and before going further just 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($admin);

Comment: No sir its not working 1st if condition is working when it comes in then again if($admin->status==0) is not working his else part is working I dnt know why its comes error on if part why it is not working

Comment: @faraz Means now you dont get the error regrading count?

Comment: Yes because i replace count with !empty and error comes in inner if condition if($admin->status==0) is not working and else condition is working when i give correct code

Comment: Its not compare with zero because inactive email status is 0  but when i use active email which is else part sith status is 1 it works

Comment: protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $admin=admin::where('email',$request->email)->first();
    if(!empty($admin))
    {
       if($admin->status){

          return ['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'status'=>1];
           
        }
        else{

          return ['email'=>'inactive','password'=>'You are not an active person, Please contact to admin'];

        }
    }
       return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}

Comment: trying to get the value of $admin->status by manually adding email in query so you need 2 admin one is which has status 0 and second is wiith status 1.and figure it out on what you get and only after that making condition as $admin->status...

Answer (score 0):

```
$admin = null;
var_dump(count($admin));
```

**output**: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in … on line 12 // as of PHP 7.2

if condition should be like:

```
if(isset($admin) && count($admin))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset($admin->id)` instead of `count($admin)`

Try this :

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $admin=admin::where('email',$request->email)->first();
    if(isset($admin->id)))
    {
       if($admin->status==0){
           return ['email'=>'inactive','password'=>'You are not an active person, Please contact to admin'];
           }
           else{
               return ['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'status'=>1];
           }
       }
       return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case count was 1 even when I got [] from api

so I had to put it in try catch

```
try{
 $propertyId = arr[0].propertyId;
}catch(\Exception $e) {
return response()->json(['success' => 'false']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ceklogin()
{
    if (isset($_POST['login']))
        $username = $this->input->post('username',true);
        $password = $this->input->post('password',true);
        $cek =$this->login_model->proseslogin($username,$password);
        $hasil = count($cek);
```

Answer (score -2):

add this your controler this code:

```
 $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
        if ($user){
            return redirect()->back()->with('errors','We cant find a user with that e-mail address.');
        }else{
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->new_password);
            $user->update();
            return redirect()->back()->with('success','Success');
        }
```