# wamp- count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, symfony, wamp, countable

i am working on symfony and got this message

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable

This message is showing only for php 7.2.14, not for php 7.1.26.

I would like a solution that is applied on the server like this one for [phpmyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co).

I know there are solutions involving changing the code like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020833/count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-countable-in-lar).

But i want a solution that is for all pages, so in the server side.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you want a solution that will apply to all pages then downgrade to php 7.1.x.  Otherwise, any software that relied on the older behavior of count will need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 7.2 now emits a warning if the count() argument is not countable. From the PHP doc :

> Version 7.2.0 : count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.

If the issue is coming from Symfony you should update to at least Symfony version 3.4 (see [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26291)).

If the issue is coming from your code, you should edit your code to only count() arrays or classes implementing the Countable interface

Comment: so no way to change something in phpMyAdmin in wamp ?

Comment: The error occurs in the phpMyAdmin page or in your website page ?

Comment: Yes. Symfony already did it for you, all you need to do is upgrade.