# Error = Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: php

$num_of_imgs = count($images['name']);

```
for ($i=0; $i < $num_of_imgs; $i++) { 
    # get the image info and store them in var
    $image_name = $images['name'][$i];
    $tmp_name   = $images['tmp_name'][$i];
    $error      = $images['error'][$i];

if ($error === 0) {
        
    $img_ex = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to my low reputation I cannot add a comment :/

What to you see when run `var_dump($images['name'])`;?

I guess this one might solve your problem:

```
count([$images['name']]);
```

Whatever $images['name'] is will be inserted into array which will allow count function to proceed.

Another option is to make sure that $images['name'] is not null. Depending on php version there might be a warning if null is passed to `count` function. For php => 7 will be like this:

> $images = $images['name'] ?? [];

Otherwise :

> $images = ($images['name']) ? $images['name'] : [];

Your questions looks like a [duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020833/count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-countable-in-lar). In general would advice first google the topic and only then add a question here : ]

Comment: I thing error appears when i add css/js from filepond, because there are nothing error when i do not use filepond

Comment: the question you posted was about why count function gives a warning. If you having issues with filepond it is a different topic I guess. Have you tried solution described in my answer? Does warning still appear?

Comment: Yeah, i already try all of your solution and the results is another error appear