# Warning in .\libraries\plugin_interface.lib.php#532

Tags: uwamp

I've the 3.1.0. of uWAMP - Php version 7.2.7

mysql 5.7.11

When I want export my Data bsae with PhpAdmin ,I've this error

Warning in .\libraries\plugin_interface.lib.php#532

How to resolve this error .
Thanks for you help.
Exuse me for my english
Marlène

Comment: Warning in .\libraries\plugin_interface.lib.php#532
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

.\libraries\display_export.lib.php#380: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Export',
array,
)
.\libraries\display_export.lib.php#883: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptionsFormat(array)
.\libraries\display_export.inc.php#74: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptions(
string 'database',
string 'omf-2018',
string '',

Answer (score 2):

Edit file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php` :

```
 sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php
```

search for :

```
if ($options != null && *count($options)* > 0) {
```

replace with :

```
if ($options != null && *count(**(array)**$options)* > 0) {
```

then restart apache service :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That's because you can now only count() on an array [php >= 7.2], and $options is not explicitly an array, so you sort of have to cast it into.

If you had this issue, you may also be interested in this post :
  [Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co)