# Getting the following error in phpMyAdmin when viewing the User_Groups Table in FileRun

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the error that phpMyAdmin displays when I look at the dr_modules_user_groups table in the Filerun database for the webserver app Filerun.

Sadly, I am far from a database expert so I do not know if this is just a warning that the application can handle, or if I need to make a correction somewhere? I don't know enough to go mucking around here without some guidance. The reason that I am even looking into the DB is because when adding Users, Roles, and Groups, I am unable to select a Group for my users, and visa versa, I am unable to select users for my Groups, so I wanted to see if possibly there was a DB reason for this, or if maybe i could manually add the Groups / User pairing from with in phpMyAdmin, which i am comforatable doing, however, I think this error could be whats causing this to not work in the first place.

If someone could please advise what the best suggestion would be to fix this, I would appreciate it.

I did not want to go and make the changes as I saw recommened for another user with the same error in this file and near the same line number,
"[phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co)" because I don't know enough about the "fix" to know if there may be any adverse conditions in my implementation, so I thought it wise to ask.

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2062: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'filerun',
string 'df_modules_user_groups',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `df_modules_user_groups`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'filerun',
string 'df_modules_user_groups',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `df_modules_user_groups`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./index.php#53: include(./sql.php)
```

I hope that I have provided enough information, if you would need anything else to help me out, please let me know. I am running on a new VPS server with a fresh mysql-server, php7.3, filerun installs on Ubuntu 18.04 LAMP install, apache2.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the risk I did not want to take, I made the following change

From:

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

and replaced the error in the syntax with the following

```
|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

Then restarted apache2

```
root@systopian-web1:>sudo service apache2 restart
```

Error in the DB is now gone. This did not fix my problem with not being able to assign users to groups and groups to users, but hey, right now, I am not complaining since the "roles" setting will work just as well I believe.