# Am trying to import some databases in phpmyadmin and am getting the following errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/display_import.lib.php#371: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Import',
array,
)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#456: PMA_getHtmlForImportOptionsFormat(array)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#691: PMA_getHtmlForImport(
string '5ddbf3eff33f7',
string 'server',
string '',
string '',
integer 2097152,
array,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
)
./server_import.php#34: PMA_getImportDisplay(
string 'server',
string '',
string '',
integer 2097152,
)
```

[Have tried the following solutions with no success](https://medium.com/@chaloemphonthipkasorn/%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89-bug-phpmyadmin-php7-2-ubuntu-16-04-92b287090b01),[phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001569/phpmyadmin-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co,https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1768071)

Comment: Are there any other errors in the PHP Error log or the MySQL error log

Comment: what is your current PHP and MySQL version and also version of your previous PHP?

Comment: no other erros @RiggsFolly