# How to display current storage used in service account with Google Drive API using PHP?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Can I ask if how will I display the current storage used in my service account of Google Drive API?

I tried to call it in fields but its not working.

```
$parameters['fields'] = 'files(storage), nextPageToken';
```

I can't seem to find a post here by typing the title but I can't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using "About: get" of Drive API? When this is reflected to the PHP script using googleapis for PHP, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your "$client".
$res = $service->about->get(['fields' => 'storageQuota']);
$storageQuota = $res -> getStorageQuota();
print_r($storageQuota);

// When you want to retrieve the value of "usage` of "storageQuota", you can do it as follows.
$usage = $storageQuota -> getUsage();
echo $usage;
```

When above script is run, the following value is obtained.

```
{
  "limit": "###",
  "usage": "###",
  "usageInDrive": "###",
  "usageInDriveTrash": "###"
}
```

#### Reference:

- [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)

Comment: have you ever run this on a service account,  whos limit is it going to show?  does the service account have its own storage quota or does it go from the owner who create it?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes. I have already tested this for both OAut2 and the service account. In this case, `storageQuota` of each service account is returned. That is different from that of user's Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks i was just curious :)

Comment: hello again sir! I'm having an error  https://imgur.com/OTZFSoq I used `foreach(` `$storageQuota as $k => $q ) {`
      `echo $q['usage'];`
     `}`
Shoud I use foreach? Please do recommend

Comment: @Mon Padi Thank you for replying. About `I'm having an error imgur.com/OTZFSoq I used foreach( $storageQuota as $k => $q ) { echo $q['usage']; } Shoud I use foreach?`, `storageQuota` is not an array. So when you want to retrieve `usage`, I added the script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying too sir! But I'm still having an error https://imgur.com/ggeTf5B and I only copy & paste your code but it is still giving me an error. This is the code: https://imgur.com/QvC7pRV

Comment: @Mon Padi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that your script has already worked. In your situation, `0` of `usage` is returned as shown in [your image](https://imgur.com/ggeTf5B). And, I think that your error message is not related to my proposed script. When you want to check your warning, how about checking this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48001569

Comment: Hello sir @Tanaike It works! Thank you again for your help :) May I know what is this number 16106127360, Is this megabyte(mb) or bytes?

Comment: @Mon Padi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, in that case, the unit is "bytes".